# how to pass json result value to dynamic fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i make a dynamic form but when i get the json result it always pass result to first row i want to pass the selected result to selected row my dynamic rows like below
i make a dynamic form but when i get the json result it always pass result to first row i want to pass the selected result to selected row my dynamic rows like below
i make a dynamic form but when i get the json result it always pass result to first row i want to pass the selected result to selected row my dynamic rows like below

and here is my ajax code:

```
$(".items").on('change',function() {
var that = $(this);
var url = "http://localhost/QuickBacklog/web/app_dev.php/invoices/invoiceitem";
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data:{'invoiceitem' : that.find('option:selected').val()},
 }).done(function( result ) {
        var description=(result.description);
        var unitprice=(result.unitprice);
        var quantity=(result.quantity);
        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
        $("#unitprice").val(+unitprice);
        $("#quantity").val(+quantity); 
 });    
});
```

my json result correct but when i pass the result it only pass the result to #description,#unitprice,#quantity not #description2,#unitprice2,#quantity2

here is my html code:

```
<select id="items" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items">
<option value="1">Clothes</option>
<option value="2">Office Stationery</option>
<option value="3">Furniture</option>
</select>
 <textarea id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="description">  </textarea>
  <input id="unitprice" class="unitprice" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;" name="unitprice">
  <input id="quantity" class="quantity" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="quantity">
  <select id="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;" name="firsttax">
  <select id="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;" name="secondtax">
```

and

```
<select id="items2" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items2">
<option value="1">Clothes</option>
<option value="2">Office Stationery</option>
<option value="3">Furniture</option>
</select>
<textarea id="description2" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="description2">   </textarea>
<input id="unitprice2" class="unitprice" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;" name="unitprice2">
<input id="quantity2" class="quantity" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="quantity2">
<select id="firsttax2" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;" name="firsttax2">
<select id="secondtax2" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;" name="secondtax2">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically generated fields.

```
$("body").on('change', '.items', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var url = "http://localhost/QuickBacklog/web/app_dev.php/invoices/invoiceitem";
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data:{'invoiceitem' : that.find('option:selected').val()},
     }).done(function( result ) {
            var description=(result.description);
            var unitprice=(result.unitprice);
            var quantity=(result.quantity);
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
            $("#unitprice").val(+unitprice);
            $("#quantity").val(+quantity); 
     });    
});
```

**Update**

put the input elements in a `div` container as like below

```
<div class='items-container'>
    <select id="items" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items">
    <option value="1">Clothes</option>
    <option value="2">Office Stationery</option>
    <option value="3">Furniture</option>
    </select>
     <textarea id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="description">  </textarea>
      <input id="unitprice" class="unitprice" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;" name="unitprice">
      <input id="quantity" class="quantity" type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;" name="quantity">
      <select id="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;" name="firsttax">
      <select id="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;" name="secondtax">
</div>
```

Instead of these lines

```
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;
$("#unitprice").val(+unitprice);
$("#quantity").val(+quantity);
```

put this script there.

```
that.parent().find('.description').val(description)
that.parent().find('.unitprice').val(unitprice)
that.parent().find('.quantity').val(quantity)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this code work but i want to store json data also in dynamic fields

Comment: like #description,#description2,#description3 and so on,how i do it?

Comment: it always store data in #description but i want whose selectbox id selected the values populate related row

Comment: add `$('.items').length` to get the number of items, so you can append this number to description etc.. like $("#unitprice"+$('.items').length) to get the random id.

Comment: i add $('.items').length but it always store unitprice in the field unit price of last row i want to store value in whose row in which i select items

Comment: can i used $this to cahnge current row values

Comment: pls show me your html code, i want to know what is `.items` here.

Answer (score 0):

use class instead of ids...

```
<input type="text" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" name="unitprice">
```

and use class selector in your success function

```
 $(".unitprice").val(+unitprice);
```

OR

the other way is to use attribut selector with `^`

```
$("textarea[id^='description']").val(description);
$('input[id^="unitprice"]').val(unitprice);
$('input[id^="quantity"]').val(quantity);
```

Comment: it will change all fields value but i want to change only the selected row value

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify selectors.

```
<div id="container1"><p id="unitprice"></p></div>
<div id="container2" style="display:none;"><p id="unitprice"></p></div>
<div id="container3" style="display:none;"><p id="unitprice"></p></div>

// ...
.done(function(result) {
    var container = $('div:visible');
    container.find('#unitprice').val(result.unitprice);
})
```